# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files in Windows 10 when using pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, dataloader

I'm doing a model of a CNN network which takes images that are located in a directory "images", and each image is located inside that directory in a directory named as the ID of the image (ex. image 1 is in: images/1/1.png).

```
class SSMDataset(Dataset):
    songs_list = []
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        """lista de nombre de canciones"""
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.songs_list = []
        self.labels_list = []
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(self.root_dir):
            for f in filenames:
                if f.endswith('.png'):
                    o = {}
                    o['img_path'] = dirpath + '/' + f
                    self.songs_list.append(o)
                elif f.endswith('.csv'):
                    o['label_path'] = dirpath + '/' + f
                    self.labels_list.append(o)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.songs_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = self.songs_list[index]['img_path']
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        fp = image.fp
        image.load()
        fp.closed
        image = np.array(image)
        image = image[np.newaxis, :, :]
        label_path = self.labels_list[index]['label_path']
        label = np.genfromtxt(label_path)
        if self.transform is not None:
            for t in self.transform:
                image, labels = t(image, label)
        return image, label
```

When I train the model, at the epoch 23 and always in taht epoch the following error raises:

Epoch: 23
39% 136/350 [00:32<00:37,  5.67it/s, accuracy=0.221, loss=1.97]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File dataloader.py line 560, in **next**
File dataloader.py line 560, in 
File  line 55, in getitem
File Image.py line 2543, in open

OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: C:\Users\...\images\1296
/1296.png

Process finished with exit code 1

I have made proof with different libraries as cv2, matplotlib...to open the image, I have use the command "with Image.open(img_path) as im:" to make sure the image is closed after it is taken but it always raises the same error and in the same epoch. I also included:

```
import torch.multiprocessing
torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')
```

in the code but the error continues to appear at the same epoch. Any idea of how could it be solved? Maybe is it a Windows problem...?

Comment: how many workers does your DataLoader use?

Comment: 0trainloader = DataLoader(dataset,
                         batch_size = batch_size,
                         num_workers=0,
                         sampler = train_sampler)